# ¿No puedo consumir api Yahoo?

Tags: api

como estan? Quiero hacer una pagina simple con una api pero por alguna razon no puedo consumirla.. Es mas estoy usando el codigo ejemplo que yahoo expone, obvio que agregando la key y lo demas personal. Me salta el error de CORS, como si tuviera origenes cruzados pero no encuentro cuales ya que todos son https. He tenido este error consumiendo la api de Marvel pero lo solucione rapido reemplazando los http por https y agregando en el head `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

Errores:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=sunnyvale%2Cca&format=json' from origin 'https://fedenu1993.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=sunnyvale%2Cca&format=json net::ERR_FAILED

En breve probare con fetch por si las dudas. Lo que mas me llama la atencion que cuando me salto el error de Marvel fue cuando lo subi a github, este sin subirlo ya tenia el error.

Esta configuracion no se si tendra que ver

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Repositorio: **https://fedenu1993.github.io/clima/**

Dejo codigo, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
    // Weather API sample javascript code
    // Requires: jQuery and crypto-js (v3.1.9)
    // 
    // Copyright 2019 Oath Inc. Licensed under the terms of the zLib license see s://opensource.org/licenses/Zlib for terms.
    
    var url = 'https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss';
    var method = 'GET';
    var app_id = 'PfF1zVaL';
    var consumer_key = 'dj0yJmk9WTVhTEFJbDZyNE5mJmQ9WVdrOVVHWkdNWHBXWVV3bWNHbzlNQT09JnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmc3Y9MCZ4PWU3';
    var consumer_secret = 'bd0e1892e78e332f24931c681a64e4402a0cbeb5';
    var concat = '&';
    var query = {'location': 'sunnyvale,ca', 'format': 'json'};
    var oauth = {
        'oauth_consumer_key': consumer_key,
        'oauth_nonce': Math.random().toString(36).substring(2),
        'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_timestamp': parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000).toString(),
        'oauth_version': '1.0'
    };
    
    var merged = {}; 
    $.extend(merged, query, oauth);
    // Note the sorting here is required
    var merged_arr = Object.keys(merged).sort().map(function(k) {
      return [k + '=' + encodeURIComponent(merged[k])];
    });
    var signature_base_str = method
      + concat + encodeURIComponent(url)
      + concat + encodeURIComponent(merged_arr.join(concat));
    
    var composite_key = encodeURIComponent(consumer_secret) + concat;
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signature_base_str, composite_key);
    var signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    
    oauth['oauth_signature'] = signature;
    var auth_header = 'OAuth ' + Object.keys(oauth).map(function(k) {
      return [k + '="' + oauth[k] + '"'];
    }).join(',');
    
    $.ajax({
      url: url + '?' + $.param(query),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': auth_header,
        'X-Yahoo-App-Id': app_id
    },
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

index:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    
        <!-- crypto-js -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script></head>
        <script src="api.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/00DLf.png
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. ¿cómo abres tu index.html? ¿en local?. Si es así, entonces quiza el origen del error está en tu navegador. Aqui un [enlace](https://www.3engine.net/wp/2021/10/como-deshabilitar-la-politica-del-mismo-origen-en-chrome/) para desactivarlo.

Comment: @DavidMiró Lo abro por una extension de vsc "Live Server" pero de misma forma lo estoy probando en github y saltan los mismo errores